# how to save data from session to the database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3 app.
I have a problem. How will I save data in my session to my database? I want to save the checkin and checkout session to the database with a datetime data type.

controller:

```
def step2
    @cart = current_cart

    checkin = params[:checkin]
    checkout = params[:checkout]
    @amenities = Amenity.available(checkin, checkout)

    session[:checkin] = checkin
    session[:checkout] = checkout
end
```

view:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :Transaction_Date, :value => Time.now %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rsv_type, :value => "Online" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rsv_status, :value => "Pending" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :checkin, session[:checkin] %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :checkout, session[:checkout] %>
<% end %>
```

im getting this error:

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `merge' for "05/18/2011":String
```

help.. please. thanks.

from my applicationcontroller:

```
private

def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
end
```

when i put these code:

```
@cart.checkin = DateTime.strptime(session[:checkin], "%m/d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").to_time
@cart.checkout= DateTime.strptime(session[:checkout], "%m/d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").to_time
@cart.save
```

i get an error of ArgumentError invalid date. :( what should i do? im using a sql server 2005 for my database.

here's my cart model

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

```
def add_amenity(amenity_id)
    current_item = line_items.where(:amenity_id => amenity_id).first
    if current_item
        return false
    else            
        current_item = LineItem.new(:amenity_id => amenity_id)
        line_items << current_item
    end
    current_item
end

def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.amenity.fee }
end

def payable
    total_price * 0.50
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass session data in your form (the last two hidden_fields in your example). In general, saving your session data is very simple.

```
# some controller action with @cart defined
@cart.checkin = session[:checkin]
@cart.checkout = session[:checkout]
@cart.save
```

Make sure to include any necessary validations on this session data to protect your system and to ensure that data saved to your database is high quality.

Also, session data shouldn't be trusted for critical information, and definitely don't use it to store passwords, financial data related to your shopping cart, etc.

---

Regarding the date part of your question, this is how to convert a string date to an actual date/time.

```
DateTime.strptime("2011/05/18 13:42:02", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S").to_time
```

Comment: im getting another error. NoMethodError undefined method `checkin=' for #<Cart:0x3bdbbc8>

Comment: @Crisgine - you have to define `@cart` properly, such as `@cart = Cart.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first`. Of course, this assumes your `Cart` model has a `checkin` field.

Comment: @Crisgine - bit of background - if you just did `@cart = Cart.where("id = ?", params[:id])`, you'd get a relation, not a single record. Even if the relation contains only one record, you have to add `first` to get something you can start changing the attributes of.

Comment: i already have a method for declaring @cart. wait, i will append it to my question and take a look. because, i don't know, how will i use that. :(

Comment: You can do all that in one line :) `@cart = Cart.find_or_create_by_id(session[:cart_id])`. This should set you up properly.

Comment: it says NoMethodError undefined method `find_or_create_by_id' :(

Comment: @Crisgine - that's strange. Are `Cart.find` and `Cart.create` working for you? If the one-liner doesn't work, you can always do this: `@cart = Cart.find_by_id(session[:cart_id])`. `if @cart.blank? ? (@cart = Cart.create) : nil`.

Comment: where should i use the DateTime.strptime ... ??

Comment: i always come up with invalid date. :( help!

Comment: In your controller, you can say `@cart.checkin = DateTime.strptime...` before saving your record. See, your session has the date in string format, so before we save the record in the controller, we say that the cart's checkin should equal the formatted date, i.e. DateTime.strptime.

Comment: Also, instead of naming your actions something like 'Step2', you should consider naming them according to the `RESTful` convention, which suggests using `new` and `create`.

Comment: when i put this: ' @cart.checkin = DateTime.strptime(session[:checkin], "%m/d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").to_time
  @cart.checkout= DateTime.strptime(session[:checkout], "%m/d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").to_time
  @cart.save' im getting an ArgumentError invalid date. what should i do? :(

Comment: @Crisgine - can you post your `Cart` model please?

Comment: @Crisgine - I'm not sure at this point, I'll think about it some more and let you know if I find the final answer. You're not far away. :)

Comment: really, thanks for the help. :) i hope it will be soon. :( because tomorrow is our deadline of passing this. T___T and im about to give up.

Comment: @Crisgine - take the `striptime` statement and debug it in your console - enter parts of it at a time and see if there is an error in the statement (I cannot find anything wrong with your model). 1) Try the example I gave you in my answer first and check for errors. 2) Try your code but substitute in an actual time in place of `session`. Tell me where it fails.

Comment: its now ok.. :) i inserted it.. without DateTime.strptime.. :) thanks a lot. my new problem is how to copy values in a table to another  table.

Comment: oops!! my bad.. sorry.. i thought i inserted it.. hahaha.. i just overlooked at it.. :(